# Filters on video file : GPUImage or Core Image?

Tags: ios, gpuimage, core-image

I have to app Apply filters on video file.which is better GPUImage or core Image?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to develop for iOS, use the CoreImage may be better. If you need to apply the filter on Android too, use the GPUImage. Because you can use almost the same shader file on these two platforms.